# Mapping dependency to property of existing component

Tags: castle-windsor

Is there a shortcut for specifying that a dependency maps to a property on an object already in the container? I know I can write a factory method to do this, just wondering if there is a more elegant way.

I can specify that component A has a dependency that maps to an instance of component B, by naming A and then writing the installer for B like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IMdiController>()
                        .ImplementedBy<MdiController>()
                        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("shell", "shell")));
```

In this example, imagine that the dependency "shell" maps not to the component "shell", but rather a property of that component (e.g., "shell.SomeProperty" - I tried this dot syntax already and it doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

I may not have understood your question correctly but perhaps what you want is a [dynamic parameter](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Inline-Dependencies.ashx) here.

Here is a description of this property from the docs:

> > There are times where you need to supply a dependency, which will not be known until the creation time of the component. For example, say you need a creation timestamp for your service. You know how to obtain it at the time of registration, but you don't know what its specific value will be (and indeed it will be different each time you create a new instance). In this scenarios you use DynamicParameters method.

In your case you could do something like the following so that the `SomeProperty` property would be called on the `Shell` component resolved from the container in order to get the value for the `something` dependency.

```
container.Register(
    Component
        .For<IMdiController>()
        .ImplementedBy<MdiController>()
        .DynamicParameters((k, d) => d["something"] = k.Resolve<Shell>().SomeProperty));
```

I am not sure if there are implications to you in calling resolve like this but maybe it is fine.

Comment: kmp, your solution is certainly viable, but it requires me to explicitly reference SomeProperty, which causes the compiler to require a reference to something I would prefer not to reference in my composition root, if I can help it. This is why I haven't used a factory method, which would be a very similar solution. I was just wondering if, since I can refer to an instance of a component in the container by name, I could refer to a property on that instance also using a name.

Comment: It occurs to me I can use a factory method or DynamicParameters delegate, and simply use reflection to get the property, treating it as a generic object - in other words, just manually do what I was wondering if I could ask the container to do by specifying the name of the property.